# LinqPad SQL Compact Edition Exception

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce, linqpad

I am getting an exception when performing a the below Linq query in LinqPad.

The Db I am using is a SQLCE (Compact edition)

SQLCeException: The specified argument value for the function is not valid. [ Argument # = 1,Name of function(if known) = LEN ]

```
from m in Menus 
where m.CategoryName.Length > 2
select m
```

or

```
Menus.Where (m => m.CategoryName.Length>5)
```

Can someone shed some light as to what is happening here?

This is the table http://i49.tinypic.com/11hs5ub.png

Comment: Check if any of the values are null..

Comment: [IMG]http://i49.tinypic.com/11hs5ub.png[/IMG]

Comment: There are no null values in the table

Comment: Yup I just seen that.. You want to check the length of data say `Electronics` has length `11` right ?

Comment: I am just wanting to do a basic select of entities that have a string length greater than 5

Comment: Can you show us what SQL is being generated - LINQPad will tell you.

Comment: `SELECT [t0].[CategoryId], [t0].[CategoryName]
FROM [Menu] AS [t0]
WHERE (CONVERT(Int,LEN(CONVERT(NText,[t0].[CategoryName])))) > @p0
-- @p0: Input Int32 (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [5]
-- Context: SqlProvider(SqlCE) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.17929`
@Phil

Comment: The same code works in my MVC project

Comment: I don't think LEN works with NText, what type if CategoryName?

Comment: CategoryName is a nvarchar. @Phil

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you a solution, but the problem is occurring because the LEN function doesn't accept an argument of type NTEXT.  Your version of Linq-to-sql is generating incorrect SQL.  Is there a more recent version of Linq to SQL and/or SQL CE you can use?

Alternatively can you use Entity Framework?